# Google Voice SMS forwarding

Tags: google-voice, iphone, sms

Due to bank limitations I need some way to send a text message to two different cell phones. My Android phone makes it easy to forward selected texts to my wife. She has an iPhone. I and others have looked but have not found the needed app for her iPhone.

Question: Can Google voice forward a received text to two numbers?

Comment: Do you want to forward specific text messages from Google Voice, or forward ALL texts to both phones? If you want ALL texts, you can add both phones in the [Google Voice settings](https://www.google.com/voice/b/0#phones).  When you add the phone, check "Receive text messages on this phone".